# Powershell recursive Find and Replace Script

Tags: powershell, recursion, replace, find, powershell-2.0

I have been using powershell to complete a recursive find and replace on a folder which will then complete the find an replace on all files in the folders and sub folders. There are roughly 1500 different values that are found and replaced.

The current code I have works for small numbers of files, but I need to run this on a 4GB folder which uses all the memory on the server (16GB RAM) and causes powershell to crash.

The below code is obviously not very efficient so does anyone know a more efficient way to complete the above task. If not does anyone know of a different programming language I could use to accomplish this task. Please keep in mind I only have a windows 2012 server to work with.

```
$folderLocation = 'D:\folder\location'


####
$files = Get-ChildItem $folderLocation * -rec
foreach ($file in $files){
    write-host "Checking File " + $file.FullName
    (get-content $file.PSPath)| 
    Foreach-Object {
        $_ -replace "find","replace0" `
        -replace "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)","scrubbed_ip" `
        -replace "name0","FILLER0" `
        -replace "name1","FILLER1" `
        -replace "name2","FILLER2" `
        -replace "name3","FILLER3" `
        -replace "name4","FILLER4" `
        -replace "name5","FILLER5" `
        .
        .
        .
        .

        -replace "name1500","FILLER1500" `




    }|
    set-content $file.PSPath
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but I think this might work better:

```
$folderLocation = 'D:\folder\location'
$tempfile = 'D:\folder\location\tempfile.tmp'


####
$files = Get-ChildItem $folderLocation * -rec
foreach ($file in $files){
    write-host "Checking File " + $file.FullName
    (get-content $file.PSPath -ReadCount 3000)| 
    Foreach-Object {
        $_ -replace "find","replace0" `
        -replace "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)","scrubbed_ip" `
        -replace 'name(\d+)','FILLER$1' |
        add-content $tempfile
       }
   Remove-Item $file
   Rename-Item $tempfile -NewName $file.name
   Remove-Item $tempfile
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mjolinor, This code executes but powershell dies with the error: Process is terminated due to a StackOverflowExecption.

Also just want to point out that in the below code the name01/02/03 was just iterating as an example, Name could be anything. Filler will always iterate though.

    -replace 'name(\d+)','FILLER$1'

Comment: Did you get anything in the output file before it died?

Comment: Yeah, it was working as expected... running through each find and replace. The file output is what is expected. The powershell screen and event viewer are not very helpful though all I get is Process is terminated due to a StackOverflowExecption.

Comment: If you have output, you should be able to determine what data it was working on when it crashed. I'd start by looking at that.